# Validate particular validation group from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I am validating some .net validators in javascript on the button client click event.

```
if (typeof (Page_Validators) != "undefined") {

            for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {

                    ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i])
                    if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {

                        alert("not valid");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("valid");
                    }                    
            }
        }
```

But if i have more than one validation groups in the same page, then on the button click of 
one button will validate all the validators in the page, not the validators associated with that button's validation group.

So is there any way to only validate validators of a particular validation group from javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Page_ClientValidate('ValidationGroup');
```

Comment: actually this is written inside a jquery click event of a button. So validation group will change on each click. Is there any way to get the validation group of a button on its click event from javascript.

Comment: @mahesh: Check out this article - http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/12/28/get-validationgroup-of-asp-net-control-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: @JamesJohnson : But how we get the validation group of a button in this case. We took controls/validators validation group, but how to get buttons validation group.

Comment: mmm - not easy - it isn't a property of the button. It's embedded in the JavaScript of the page. This post is helpful http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/asp-net/17/10178886/changing-validation-group-of-button-with-javascript-on-client-side.aspx. You woud either assign it yourself in Javascript then it would be available or it is available in the button click event allegdely. I would take a control you know is in the same validation group as the button and use that - not ideal